# Is it possible to stop Google Maps from slanting the image?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

See this map: [http://imgur.com/a/r03rk](https://imgur.com/a/r03rk)

Is it possible to stop Google Maps from slanting the image like this?

If so, how?

Maybe disabling webGL would help? However, I dont think I can do this in code so it would affect all users, instead my own browser only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Map , the tilt option can be set to 0 so that the map will no longer automatically tilt (slant) when the user zooms in. 
For example:

```
 var mapOptions = {
    center: mycenter,
    zoom: 7,
    tilt: 0
};
```

Unfortunately the icon to switch tilt back on (slanting the image) will still be available on the map for the user to switch on if they wish. There is no simple way to stop this icon appearing.
[image]

Comment: `rotateControl: false` map option disallows user to change tilt and use 45 imagery